# Usage and problems of mandelbrot set and julia set

Tags: algorithm, math, mandelbrot

What is the usage of mandelbrot set and julia set in programming? Is there any sample competitive problems that use these set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the Mandelbrot set (and Julia set alike) is computed to produce beautiful fractal pictures and animations, and there aren't any other good reasons to compute it.

Designing algorithms to compute Mandelbrot efficiently requires skills in complex analysis, bigint arithmetic, and low-level assembly code optimization.

Using Mandelbrot for competitive problems would be problematic due to floating-point round-off errors, which can make it hard to compare results and tell which one is correct. Though depending on what you mean by competitive, you could consider that making Mandelbrot deep zoom videos to be competitive (with bigger and bigger magnification factors) - you can see YouTube for examples.

Comment: I found this link on this as well : http://www.fractalforums.com/fractal-related-links/real-life-application-of-the-mandelbrot-and-julia-set/ - not worthy of an answer in its own right, but you might want to have it for reference in the first sentence...

Comment: Is there any other set or designing algorithm? (I'm kinda interested in this :v) thanks for your comment before